# Shell script use ssh forwarding to send a file to a second system

Tags: shell-script, ssh, file-copy, forwarding

I have ssh forwarding enabled and ssh to server A. On server A I want to run a script as root and take advantage of the ssh key being forwarded for USER to send a file to system B. I'm getting a permission denied when trying to run the following.

```
# runuser -l USER -c "scp filename.tgz serverB:~/"
```

Comment: First check you can access serverB `ssh user@serverB`

Comment: Yes, all the servers have the key for user. Server A is  a staging server. To access server B I have to mySystem->ServerA->ServerB, mySystem->ServerA->ServerC. Direct ssh access to B and C isn't possible. This is done though key forwarding.